# Datatable null to empty string

Tags: c#, linq, datatable, dataset

I have a datatable with **null** values as well. I need to replace all **null** with string.empty in linq in c#.
Please suggest.

Answer (score 8):

Don't use LINQ if you want to modify something (in `LINQ-To-Objects`)

```
foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
{
    foreach (DataColumn col in table.Columns)
    {
        if (row.IsNull(col) && col.DataType == typeof(string))
            row.SetField(col, String.Empty);  
    }
}
```

Comment: I have no specific column name.I need to loop through the entire columns in datatble

Comment: @Saritha.S.R: I've edited my answer to loop all rows and columns and also to avoid an `ArgumentException` if you have a column that is not of type `string`.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if it's null using:

```
DBNull.Value.Equals(itemToCheck)
```

Then you can replace the value with an String.Empty.